# aws-auth in eks fargate, how does the cluster creator get admin rights

Tags: security, amazon-eks

I'm trying to wrap my head around the aws-auth configmap.  I think I have figured out how it works, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how the cluster creator gets admin rights.  When I look at the aws-auth config map, I see the following

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      - system:node-proxier
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::accountID:role/eksctl-name-cluster-FargatePodExecutionRole-1JTMRBGU971E6
      username: system:node:{{SessionName}}
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-02T00:16:39Z"
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "1475"
  uid: 45cf22e7-fd8d-4c07-bb90-77e02a74518a
```

I can see `mapRoles` but I'm not sure how this comes into play, and I don't see the `admins` group mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

> ...stuck trying to figure out how the cluster creator gets admin rights.

It is explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/amazon-eks-cluster-access/):

```
You don't need to add cluster_creator to the aws-auth ConfigMap to get admin access to the Amazon EKS cluster. By default, the cluster_creator has admin access to the Amazon EKS cluster that it created.
```

Comment: thanks for this, but how does it know who the cluster creator is, I mean in the initial config I posted there is nothing indicating this.

Comment: The identity of the creator is not store in the aws-auth. It is separately managed by EKS within and not accessible by end user.

Comment: thanks for this, how do I view who the creator of a particular cluster is ?